# Finding $\mathbb{P}(A\cup B\cup C)$ under following assumptions

Tags: probability

> $$\mathbb{P}(A)=0.3$$
>
> $$\mathbb{P}(B)=0.4$$
>
> $$\mathbb{P}(C)=0.5$$
>
> $$\mathbb{P}(B|C)=0.5$$
>
> $A$ and $B$ are mutual exclusive $$(A\cap B=\emptyset )$$
>
> and A and C are independent $$(\mathbb{P}(A\cap C)=\mathbb{P}(A)\cdot
>  \mathbb{P}(C))$$
>
> Determine $\mathbb{P}(A\cup B\cup C)$

**What I Tried:**

I tried to use the multiplication formula $\mathbb{P}(A\cap B\cap C)=\mathbb{P}(A)\cdot \mathbb{P}(B|A)\cdot  \mathbb{P}(C|A\cap B)$ but it did not bring me any further (I used the de Morgan laws to get everywhere an intersection and then apply the multiplication formula).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

We use inclusion-exclusion.

$$P(A\cup B\cup C) = P(A)+P(B)+P(C)-P(AB)-P(AC)-P(CB)+P(ABC)$$

We are told that $AB = \varnothing$ which implies that $ABC = \varnothing$, and
$$P(AB)  = P(ABC) = 0.$$

So we have
$$P(A\cup B\cup C) = P(A)+P(B)+P(C)-P(AC)-P(CB).$$

Comment: So I got the following result:

Comment: It is missing..

Comment: $\mathbb{P}(C|B)\Rightarrow \mathbb{P}(C\cap B)=0.2$

then $\mathbb{P}(A)+\mathbb{P}(B)+\mathbb{P}(C)-\mathbb{P}(A)\cdot \mathbb{P}(C)-\mathbb{P}(C\cap B)=1.2-0.15-0.2=0.85$

Sorry, i hit enter on the first comment.

Comment: No, not quite. Your first line is incorrect. We have $$P(CB) = P(B|C)P(C) = .5\cdot .5 = .25$$ where I used the product rule in the second equality.

Comment: Oh yea , you are right I changed the depending variable! Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Consider giving a [check mark $\checkmark$](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). Good luck!